# Convert htaccess rewrite rules script to nginx config

Tags: apache-http-server, conversion, nginx, htaccess, rewrite

please hlep with this script...

i want convert htaccess rewrite rules script to nginx config.

.htaccess:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

how i can?

I want apply this on one folder on server ... and contains subfolders.
My magic test is, but ended error 404:

```
location /comp {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /comp/index.php?/$request_uri;
    if (!-f www/comp$fastcgi_script_name) {
        return 404;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try removing the `if` block.

Comment: After removed `if` lock then not acceptable for subfolders in "comp" folder. This rule applied for comp folder only.